# Ignore invalid cross-references in Weaviate import

Tags: weaviate

Is there a way to disable the checks when uploading objects to Weaviate?
I get the error

`{'message': "invalid cref: 'cref' MyClass:MyProperty: no object with id .... found}`

But I would like to proceed with the upload anyways. (The goal is to reduce the amount of Weaviate calls by inserting the references in the objects instead of separately uploading the references later)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Define the cross ref properties in advance at class creation or add the cross ref property to class before adding the cross refrencs , note the cross ref property names need be camelcased or the batch add reference call will most likey fail.